# SQL ExtendedProperty When using code first EF

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, code-first

I'm in the research phase of determining if we should move to an ORM at my work. Entity Framework (we'd be using the latest at time of switchover which I believe at the moment is 6.1) is a strong candidate given that our main app is C# WCF on the service layer and SQL Server on the backend (though we'd like to break that dependency via moving a lot of business logic out of stored procs).

Anyways: we use SQL extended properties to document what each column and table does. Is there a way to specify when you are doing a code first model what the extended properties on the database should be for the corresponding column/table? If not how do you document the database or do you just rely on anyone looking at your database having access to your source code too (which might not be the case for 3rd party distributors for example)?

Comment: Can't be done with code-first. Maybe database-first is the best option for you.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Perhaps a relatively minor feature request for the next version is in order. We can't be the only shop more comfortable with C# but still requiring publishing a somewhat documented Db schema for 3rd parties.